# react-paginate module does'not work

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I am trying to use "react-paginate" module for pagination.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

When I clone the repo it works absolutely fine. But when I try to imp[ort it in my project, css are missing.

Can anyone help?

```
 <ReactPaginate
      previousLabel="previous"
      nextLabel="next"
      breakClassName="break-me"
      pageCount={5}
      marginPagesDisplayed={2}
      pageRangeDisplayed={5}
      onPageChange={() => {}}
      containerClassName="pagination"
      subContainerClassName="pages pagination"
      activeClassName="active"
    />
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3eZx.png)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you share some code? With this description I am pretty sure your question would get downvoted and closed :)

Comment: https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate/issues/215 . Looks like something broke in the latest release.. Can you try with version 5.2.2 once?

Comment: I have tried with version 5.2.2 but its same issue. I do not get any  error but it doesnot contain any css and id displayed just as a list of numbers

Comment: I had used this repository maybe a year back for my project with dependency as `"react-paginate": 4.2.0"`. Can you going down few versions and checking if it works fine?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same issue

Comment: Can u check version in your `package-lock.json` once and share?

Comment: Also did u try this? https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate/blob/v5.2.3/demo/js/demo.js ? You can pass styles are props acc to your needs. I built it the same way when i was working on it